# Segregation Of DDL & DML Script - Flyway

Tags: java, spring, oracle, flyway

I have list of Flyway Scripts(100+) for Oracle.

When i release my package to Customer environment the User Created for our Spring Boot application only allows DML script execution, DDL can by executed only be Customer DBA Team.

Now need to separate DDL & DML as 2 script from 100+ flyway scripts, is there any tools available to get it segregated automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I would create the 2 scripts with dbforge. But for this you need a license.